# Did TPL Dataflow get cut?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I was going to play around with TPL dataflow, but I can't seem to find it anywhere in VS 2012 (including inside of the extensions and updates/nuget dialog).  Did they cut it, or am I just looking in the wrong place?

Comment: in the nuget dialog, make sure the "include prerelease" is being used

Comment: @JamesManning That's not necessary anymore, stable version of TDF was released on 21 August.

Comment: @svick - thanks. I was just taking a guess since OP said they had looked in NuGet dialog already. :)

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed IMO.  Knowing what is in the framework and how much effort MS is putting into maintaining active project (out of the huge amount of code they've shipped over the years) is very important for those of us on the MS stack.  This is very relevant to our jobs as programmers.  If subjective or answered better on other sites, maybe.  But SO ranks better than random MS blogs in google, so most of us will find a definitive answer on SO first.  That should be enough to keep questions like this open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TPL Dataflow was moved from the framework itself to NuGet.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/05/30/mef-and-tpl-dataflow-nuget-packages-for-net-framework-4-5-rc.aspx) So, now, to use it from your project, you need to get it from NuGet (right click References → Manage NuGet packges).

The reason given for this change is so that TPL Dataflow could be updated more frequently, not just when the whole framework is updated.

Comment: One thing I didn't understand -- I found it in nuget, but not in the UI -- I had to use the package manager and load it from the command line as listed here: https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow I don't understand why it didn't show up in the nuget gui

Comment: It shows there just fine for me. No idea why you would have any problems with it.

Comment: That would be because I'm an idiot.  I was using the "extensions manager", and not the package manager - the UI looks so similar that I didn't realize that I was in the wrong one.  Thanks for your help.